# How can my Perl code catch Ctrl+D?

Tags: perl

```
chomp($input = <>);
```

How do I know whether `$input` is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>?

Comment: As in how do you know when the input has ended, or how do you know that the user sent ctrl-D as opposed to, say, piping in a file which has reached the end?

Answer (score 2):

You know you have reached eof when you get undef from `<>`, but in your case the `chomp` is hiddening it.

The usual Perl idiom to read until EOF is as follows:

```
while(<>) {
  chomp;
  # do whatever you want with the line in $_
  # ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess in your question `ctrl-d` is tantamount to `EOF`, as on UNIX? With some filehandle in `$fh`:

```
while ( <$fh> ) {
  # use $_ here
}
```

Or, if you insist on being explicit to spell out what Perl does behind the scenes:

```
while ( defined( $_ = <$fh> ) ) {
  # use $_ here
}
```

Or use some other variable:

```
while ( defined( my $in = <$fh> ) ) {
  # use $in here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Everyone seems to be adding a lot to the question that you asked.

Simply put, for:

```
chomp($input = <>);
```

You can tell that `^D` has been pressed via:

```
print "EOF reached\n" if not defined $input;
```